# Why locally-saved HTML page cannot be opened by a browser?

Tags: browser, web-scraping, html

I saved this page 'https://www.applebees.com/en/locations/results?searchQuery=London' to a local file by using the browser-provided 'save as'.
The address I put into the browser is:
'file:///users/Kobe/Documents/applebees.html'
where '/users/Kobe/Documents/applebees.html' is the file path on Mac system.

However, when I tried to reopen the local file, the browser says: 
Cannot find the IP address of 'users' server.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Did you save it as a .html file?

Comment: @DManokhin yes I did

Comment: did you try another browser ?

Comment: @DanielEuchar yes, all failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove space from file name

```
Location Results.html
```

to

```
LocationResults.html
```

Comment: The file name is 'applebees.html'